# Order of elements before nth element after call to std::nth_element

Tags: c++

I am interested in the most efficient way to find the first (left-most) element in a vector that is equal to the median. Finding the median is simple:

```
std::nth_element(first, middle, last);
auto median = *middle;
```

However if the input is like {2, 2, 2, 2, 1}, then after calling std::nth_element, there will be 2s before the middle element. Do I have to search all values to the left of the middle? Or is it guaranteed that the 2s will all be adjacent?

Another way to ask this is whether {2, 1, 2, 2, 2} is possible after calling std::nth_element as above, or is {1, 2, 2, 2, 2} guaranteed? In the latter case, I can just search left from the middle. In the former, I have to search from first to middle, which is less efficient. From empirical testing, it appears that the latter case holds. Wondering if anyone has a definitive answer or if I am missing some corner-case.

Comment: Do you need the elements equal to the median to be adjacent? Or do you just need to find the first one which is equal to the median?

Comment: Yes. I mis-stated the problem. I need to partition the sequence based on the  median, so I just need to call std::partition after finding the median. Or perhaps there is an algorithm that partitions on the median directly?

Comment: auto pivot = begin(y);
  advance(pivot, distance(pivot, end(y)) / 2);
  nth_element(begin(y), pivot, end(y));
  auto pred = bind(less<double>(), _1, *pivot);
  pivot = partition(begin(y), pivot, pred);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation only guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element):

> - The element pointed at by nth is changed to whatever element would occur in that position if [first, last) was sorted.
> - All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element.

Note that there are *no* guarantees that the elements before or after the nth element appear in any particular order, so long as the ones before are less than or equal to it (and by extension, due to the nature of it being the nth element, the elements after it are greater than or equal to it); both `{2, 1, 2, 2, 2}` and `{1, 2, 2, 2, 2}` would be perfectly legal orderings.

Answer (score 0):

nth element does not guarantee anything about the order of elements before the nth.

It may be hard to impelment without clumping elements equal to the nth, or on small lists it just sorts, so that is probably what you are seeing.

---

It may help to understand how nth element may be implemented: this is just an example.

One way to implement nth element is to do median of 5.  Take your collection and divide it into clumps of 5.  Sort each clump (O(1)*O(n)).  Now repeat on the median of the 5 element clumps to find its true median (using nth element).

Eventually you'll get single element that is close to the middle (between 0.3 and 0.7), and it takes linear time.  (

Do partition of your sequence (linear time), and you now where the element is in order in your sequence (by counting).

If it is the nth element and you are loking for the kth and k

As you are searching an exponentially smaller region with a linear time algorithm, this entire algorithm is linear time.

Note that this can seriously jumble up the order of elements; there is zero guarantee equal elemenra are a adjacent.

See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians for more details.